# Trying to fetch image URL in Swift using Google Image API

Tags: json, api, swift

I'm trying to use the google image API with JSON (https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide) to get the URL of the first image that shows when searching something. This is what I have:

```
let placeName = "New York"

func getImage() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=\(placeName)")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){ (response, go, error) -> Void in
    let go = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(go, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil) as [String:AnyObject]
        let responseData = go["responseData"] as [String:AnyObject]
        // let results = responseData["results"] as [String:AnyObject]
        // let imageURL = results["unescapedUrl"] as String
        println(responseData)
}
}
```

The responseData part is as far as I can go (that then returns everything), but trying to go one level deeper (to "results") will crash it.

Comment: I suggest you use alamofire and SwiftyJson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare results as a dictionary but your linked Google page shows an example where results is an array of dictionaries.

You can do this instead:

```
let results = responseData["results"] as [[String:String]]
let firstObject = results[0]
let firstURL = firstObject["unescapedUrl"]
```

Comment: knew it would be a simple fix.